# Capital letter after dash and space "- Example"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand how to set up a rule that checks if letters after a dash and a space are capitalized. Basically what I want is a simple check:

```
"- any" = WRONG 
"- Any" = RIGHT
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Any attempt? It's easier and you'll learn faster if we can correct a not working regex to highlight errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=-\s+[A-Z]).*$
```

Try this.Put flags `m` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rN2uM2/1

Comment: Thanks! Through your example and your amazing link (as I said this is the first time I try to create a regex) I was able to set up the checker: -\s[a-z]